# Legendre transformation

Tags: differential-geometry

This is a problem from Zorich's Analysis.I am doing a project for final year maths and I would like to understand a bit more about the following subject, in order to introduce an application in my poster. I mention that my knowledge is elementary, up to implicit/inverse function theorem ( inclusive), but I am not really able to apply these in exercises.

Define $$\xi_i=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x^i}}(x^1,\ldots,x^m),\forall i\in{1,\ldots,m}$$ and
$$ f^{*}(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_m)= \sum_{i=1}^{m}\xi_ix^i-f(x^1,\ldots,x^m).$$

1. In the problem we are asked a geometric interpretation of this transformation. I think of that as attaching at each point on the surface the tangent hyperplane (of m variables) and then somehow ''wrap'' it up. Is this correct? Can we make this a bit more rigorous?
2. The second part of the question ask to prove that if $f\in C^{(2)}$ and any second partial derivative is nonzwero, then we are guaranteed to be able to do this transformation. Can someone explain me why? thank you

Comment: See if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802356/a-definition-of-the-legendre-transform-from-zorich/1802545#1802545) helps

Comment: See also [this nice explanation](http://onmyphd.com/?p=legendre.fenchel.transform)

Comment: Use capitals for names: "legendre" $\to$ "Legendre" (I have done it in the title for you).